# Is $\prod_{p}{\frac{p-1}{p+1}}=0$?

Tags: limits, number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic, products

Is it true that the 
$$\prod_{p}{\frac{p-1}{p+1}}=0$$ where the product runs over the prime numbers $p$?

Comment: $\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p}$ is divergent hence it holds for sure. Can you prove that $\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p}$ is divergent?

Comment: Hint: for any $s>1$, $$\sum_{p}\frac{1}{p^s} = O(1)+\sum_{p}-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right) = O(1)+\log\zeta(s) $$ and the Riemann $\zeta$ function has a pole (with residue $1$) at $s=1$.

Comment: Sure there is simple theorem proving this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes

Comment: Of course. It is interesting to prove that the same sum ranging over *twin* primes is indeed convergent. That is usually done through Brun's sieve.

Comment: [A closely related product](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/22411/11619) with a bit more information about the rate of divergence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a theorem stating that $$  \prod_{i=0}^{\infty} (1-a_i)=0 \iff \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i=\infty \quad\quad\quad0 <a_i<1$$

$$$$

Therefore, yes, it converges to zero sice $\frac{p-1}{p+1}=1-\frac{2}{p+1}$ and $\sum_p \frac{1}{p} = \infty$.

Comment: That's a good theorem! Does it have a name?

Comment: @StellaBiderman I don't know. but it's well-known in real analysis.

Comment: @StellaBiderman It has been mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product

Comment: Follows from $e^x < 1/(1-x)$ if $0 < x < 1$. Look at the power series to see a proof.

Comment: @martycohen yeah,thanks

Comment: It's a discovery of Leonhard Euler that $\prod_{p\in P}\;(1-p^{-1})=0.$ His collected works, on paper, will literally fill a room. So nothing is called "Euler's Theorem".

Comment: @user254665 Thanks.

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/475769/11619)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks.